# Difference between default and regular typescript exports?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Just want to see whether I understand the difference between typescript exports that use the default keyword and 'normal' exports.  For example:

```
import validate from "./StaticZipCodeValidator";
```

In this case we don't need to to surround validate with curly `{}` braces, since it's the default export of "./StaticZipCodeValidator";

So when exporting defaults we don't use curly braces as shown here:

```
declare let $: JQuery;
export default $;
```

And when importing we also don't use curly braces.  Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And when importing we also don't use curly braces. Did I miss anything?

No.

That said. Personally I don't use default exports [for various reasons](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html). I have seen  other OSS libraries making the choice to avoid this feature as well.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript modules are an implementation of ES6 modules. I suggest [the ES6 introduction to modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) from Mozilla:

> ```
> import _ from "lodash";
> ```
>
> This shorthand is equivalent to `import {default as _} from "lodash";`.
>
> [...] There’s nothing magic about a default export; it’s just like any other export, except it’s named `"default"`.

The member `default` is intended to replace the CommonJS `module.exports =`. It is better because we keep the ability to export additional things later.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a file (module). A module can have multiple clases, abstractions, and interfaces.

Then, when you import a non default class, abstractions, or interface you have to use the curly braces, otherwise you import de default exported component.

```
import {NotDefaultClass} from "DefaultExportedClass";

import DefaultExportedClass from "DefaultExportedClass";
```